# Why is Self being called to access the Class's own property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, properties

I'm slightly confused with a certain concept. The best way to ask my question is to illustrate  it with an example. Now in the below code I declare a property called loan and I synthesize this property. Now this might seem like a nooby question but I'm assigning the value "250.00" to loan. I've seen tutorials around the web that might do "self.loan = 250.00;" VS my "loan = 250.00;" Both ways seem to accomplish the same thing. But why do people use "self.propertyName" to access a property, when using the property name itself is enough?

```
//ClassA.h
@interface ClassA: UIViewController
@property double loan;
@end

//ClassA.m
@implementation ClassA
@synthesize loan;

-(void)doSomething{
  loan = 250.00;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@synthesize` also generates an underlying instance variable for your property, which is unfortunately named the same as the property by default.

This means that when you use `loan = 250.0`, you're really accessing the underlying instance variable directly, rather than via. the property accessor. You can see this if you change your `@synthesize` line to:

```
@synthesize loan = _loan;
```

Now your code no longer compiles and you must use either `self.loan` to access it via. the generated property accessors, or `_loan` to access the underlying instance variable.

Comment: Ok I see. So for example would this be correct "self.loan = 10 + _loan;" And this would be incorrect "self.loan = 10 + self.loan;"

Comment: Both are correct: `self.loan = 10 + self.loan` is translated by the compiler to be `[self setLoan:10 + [self loan]]` (using the methods generated by `@synthesize`). It is almost always preferable to use `self.loan` (property accessors) instead of `_loan` (direct instance variables).

Answer (score 2):

They aren't exactly the same.

```
self.loan = 250.00;
```

is really shorthand for

```
[self setLoan:250.00];
```

which is a method call; whereas `loan = 250.00` just writes that value directly to the appropriate part of memory.

This difference matters when, for example, another piece of code is using Key-Value Observing to monitor changes to the loan property. By calling `setLoan:`, all the proper notifications will be fired. By setting `loan` directly, they will not.

Also, if you aren't using Automatic Reference Counting, the set method will ensure that the new value is retained and old value release properly. (If you are using ARC, this is automatically taken care of either way.)

Answer (score 1):

Its because `self.loan` references the property while `loan` just references the underlying variable. It is key for reference types that have the `retain`, `copy` or other modifiers.